# Opening an Excel File in Notepad gives un related data

Tags: excel, notepad

I am downloading an excel attachment from an email using a tool and converting that file to CSV Using VB Script. The problem I am facing is, after converting the file to CSV, when I try to open the file using notepad, it shows boxes instead of the correct data. But the same file if opened using an excel then it returns the correct data. 
                But if I create a mew CSV file and open it with notepad I am not facing this problem. kindly help me !!!

Comment: Surely it's obvious that we can't help you without seeing your VBScript code for converting the file to CSV? You're clearly not succeeding in actually creating a CSV, just a file with a `.csv` extension that's still in some other format. Impossible to say why without seeing the code.

Comment: And what does this have to do with Java?!

Comment: Hi Crowder
Thank you for your reply. The problem is once I get the excel attachment from email and open it with notepad, i'm facing he problem, So the problem is not by converting from excel to CSV

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your script, I would guess that the file is simply *renamed* to a .csv file - but not actually converted! This way, you would end up seeing the binary data in Notepad.

Try to open the original Excel file in Excel - and there save it as .csv. This will surely work, i.e. you'll see the data in Notepad.

If that does not help, please share your script.